# Spring MVC : How to pass model object to controller method with out using form

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a controller class where i am adding an object to model, On view i can access it, and now i want to send this object back to a new controller method, Is it possible to do it with out using form? and example code is:

Here i am adding 'details' to model.

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ModelAndView method1() {
       .....
        mv.addObject("details", details);
         mv.setViewName(REVIEW_PAGE);
         return mv;
}
```

I have an "Ok" button on review page where details are reviewed. Now i want to send this "details" object back to a new method for submission.
i want to access the details object in this second method of same controller class.

I have tried to add this as model attribute (as you can see in following code) but i am getting null values inside details object.

```
@RequestMapping(....)
public ModelAndView method2(@ModelAttribute("details") Details details){
//access details object here        

}
```

The flow is like : ( add details in model (method1) --> send to view for review --> confirm (click ok) --> send back for submission (method2))

I am new to Spring MVC so if there are mistakes in my question, i am sorry for that.

Comment: why do you need to re-submit the model which is already available at server-sider?

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Spring to keep a copy of the model on the server side by using the `@SessionAttributes` annotation on the controller

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("details")
public class TheController {
}
```

This comes with some caveats.  The default built-in implementation is pretty basic and does not, for example, account for multi-tab browsers using the same session across tabs.  It also has no automatic cleanup.  You have to manually call `session.setComplete()` when you are done with the data.

Comment: actually i am not using session

Comment: then you will need to do something to send the information back from the client side, a form is certainly simplest.

Comment: It's Either SessionAttributes or Form. 
In the form, you don't necessarily need inputs. just <c:out> are fine to display information on the page to review.
the OK button is still a type submit. with your modelAttribute and action url is where you want to send your data.